# Is there any reason to install the demo while I'm downloading the game?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I am twiddling my thumbs waiting for the 10 gig download to complete and I noticed a post that said playing the Mass Effect 3 demo would give me some DLC in Kingdoms of Amalur.

I've already got the ME3 gear for playing the KOA demo, is it worthwhile to grab the Mass Effect 3 demo to get that gear or is it particularly outclassed by a moderate amount of game play?

Comment: I've removed the KOA tag from your question since this question really isn't about KOA at all, it's about ME3. Feel free to add it back in if you disagree.

Comment: @Wipq Isn't it the opposite? He's asking about the items you get in KoA from playing the ME3 demo.

Comment: @bwarner you're right... my apologies. Apparently I'm failing at reading comprehension today.

Comment: So, I've now switched out the ME3 ta got KOA for the same reason I stated in the first post, but with @bwarners correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the "demo DLC" in KoA gets obsolete pretty quick.  The [Omniblade](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Omniblades) daggers and the N7 armor (which is Might-focused, I believe) isn't all that exciting.  It rather quickly ended up in my stash and stayed there through most of the game.

You can also unlock the N7 armor by inputting the KoA Online Pass, which makes playing the ME3 demo to unlock it somewhat redundant.

On the whole, I'd say it isn't worth it unless you haven't gotten very far in KoA - if you're past the first town, you've probably found better equipment from chests or random drops.